# I have bug with google signIn. google_sign_in_web 0.11.0 & google_sign_in 6.0.0

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I have had working code to google sign.
Now, I want to upgrade google sign in library version, because of google has plan to deprecate current api.
I updated the version and code, but it's not work.
Can you help me?

---

I use `google_sign_in: ^6.0.0`.
And I wrote google sign in code like below by referring to the following link.

- https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart

```dart
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    clientId: '..',
    scopes: <String>[
      'email',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
    ]
);

void signInSilently() {
  _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
    print('signInsilently log!!');
    print(account);
    if (account != null) {
      _handleGetContact(account!);
    }
  });

  _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
}

Future<void> _handleGetContact(GoogleSignInAccount user) async {
  final http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections'
        '?requestMask.includeField=person.names'),
    headers: await user.authHeaders,
  );
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    print('People API ${response.statusCode} response: ${response.body}');
    return;
  }
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
}


Future<void> signIn() async {
  signInSilently();
  var googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  print(googleSignInAccount);
}
```

And this is my error.
The application show dialog to login google.
But when i logged in, it logged error log like below.

```
[GSI_LOGGER-OAUTH2_CLIENT]: Checking popup closed.
[GSI_LOGGER-OAUTH2_CLIENT]: Checking popup closed.
[GSI_LOGGER-OAUTH2_CLIENT]: Checking popup closed.
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: Handling response. {"access_token":"ya29.a0AVvZVsrjmqr9B1aR5YtG5laxlU5DFvD8OXgxCEzFs3coO7rtPRXxekaJRYXpkD7toxNVKV0Qw40pRU28_-rjXPOYduWewbWzDSENdDV-GN4NmXdki8F1bmg4xR97Xio8G52_ojiOMn2xA0JCkH-SIWvxsCICkQaCgYKAYcSARESFQGbdwaIK-xPIdxFe4pyMbpGNhZ8XA0165","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"scope":"email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid","authuser":"0","prompt":"none"}
[GSI_LOGGER-OAUTH2_CLIENT]: Popup timer stopped.
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: Trying to set gapi client token.
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: The OAuth token was not passed to gapi.client, since the gapi.client library is not loaded in your page.
Error: {
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
packages/google_sign_in_web/src/people.dart 146:7                                                                          _doRequest
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                          runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                    handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                    _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 566:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 639:7                                     callback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: May be you're to signin twice.
First with `_googleSignIn.signInSilently();` and then with `await _googleSignIn.signIn();`

Comment: got the exact same error following the library update to 6.0.0

Comment: @Rosenpin do you know how to fix?

Comment: Same error with me. Any ideas why did that happen?

Answer (score 2):

Actually @Rosenpin is more or less right. The `signInSilently` will not always work, if the session in the browser is not found it will return null. But if the user is logged in the browser it will silently sign in.

So if you are in chrome browser and sign in, when clicking the button you will get the `signInSilently` to work as expected.

If you are not signed in the browser, like when running the debug mode from flutter, you will get this logs on the browser indicating the error:

```
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: Instantiated.
[GSI_LOGGER]: No sessions found in the browser.
[GSI_LOGGER]: Prompt will not be displayed
[google_sign_in_web] Error on CredentialResponse:
[google_sign_in_web] Removing error from `userDataEvents`:
```

To solve this you can check if `signInSilently` has returned null and you are on the web, do the normal Sign In. Like this:

```
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
        kIsWeb ? await (googleSignIn.signInSilently()) : await (googleSignIn.signIn());

    if (kIsWeb && googleSignInAccount == null) googleSignInAccount = await (googleSignIn.signIn());
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to SignInSilently before to get an IdToken with this Flutter package, for authentication, then you use SignIn for Authorization of the scopes

See documentation :

> The GIS SDK only provides an idToken (JWT-encoded info) when the user
> successfully completes an authentication flow. In the plugin:
> signInSilently. The plugin signIn method uses the Oauth "Implicit
> Flow" to Authorize the requested scopes.
>
> If the user hasn't signInSilently, they'll have to sign in as a first step of the Authorization popup flow.
> If signInSilently was unsuccessful, the plugin will add extra scopes to signIn and retrieve basic Profile information from the
> People API via a REST call immediately after a successful
> authorization. In this case, the idToken field of the
> GoogleSignInUserData will always be null.

Comment: I called signSilently before signin at `signIn()`.
Did it need to be done at init?
Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

From the new version of `sign_in_web` library documentation:
[image: documentation relating to issues with signInSilently]

In other words, `signInSilently` was changed to conform to the new Google sign in library stateless mode. This means that it will always return null and in my case (seems like in yours too) it conflicts with the standard `signIn` call.

What I did to fix it was remove the `signInSilently` call and only call the `signIn` function with the appropriate scopes.

In your case, if you work on a multiplatform app, I'd just change your signInSilently function to:

```
void signInSilently() {
  _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
    print('signInsilently log!!');
    print(account);
    if (account != null) {
      _handleGetContact(account!);
    }
  });

  if (kIsWeb) {
      print('skipping silent login on web');
      return;
  }
  _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
}
```

More information can be found here:
https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web

Comment: it's not work for me. it gives me access_token & id & email. can i use access token or id as parameter to check google verify? can you share server-side code? (in my case i use java GoogleIdTokenVerifier)

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem doing Google signin in in Flutter web or even mobile. Check this:

- [fully working example by Google](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart)
- Read this article if you want to get [an OAuth client ID](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid)

Dont forget to upvote and Good luck ❤️